# "Плющит" Button в menu. Почему?

Tags: java, android, xml

!(https://pp.userapi.com/c851216/v851216700/13fe2/rfT0U8kIW_4.jpg)

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/edAddNewNote"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/add_check_note"/>
```

Comment: Все ли в порядке с drawable add_check_note?

Comment: Да, он нормально отображается.

Comment: покажите drawable/add_check_note